# Java - Read data from a json with the JSON library according to an object

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON with some data and I would like to print as follows

```
10 REGISTER 1, KP SUM 2081,606
20 REGISTER 2 CH SUM 0,22
```

Where the general sum is calculated by the total sum of the items according to the code.

Following the rule, first multiply the quantity by the unit and then add all the items that have the same code.

Example:

```
code 10
SUM = 0,0200000 * 7,40 + 10,0000000 * 200,31 + 0,5690000 * 40,19 + 0,7890000 * 70,33
```

The same goes for the other codes that appear in JSON

My JSON

```
    [
      {
        "code": 10,
        "description": "REGISTER 1",
        "unity": "KP",
        "typeItem": "I",
        "itemCode": 1,
        "descriptionItem": "ITEM",
        "unityItem": "UN",
        "quantity": "0,0200000",
        "valueUnity": "7,40"
      },
      {
        "code": 10,
        "description": "REGISTER 1",
        "unity": "KP",
        "typeItem": "I",
        "codeItem": 2,
        "descriptionItem": "ITEM 2",
        "unityItem": "UN",
        "quantity": "10,0000000",
        "valueUnity": "200,31"
      },
      {
        "code": 10,
        "description": "REGISTER 1",
        "unity": "KP",
        "typeItem": "I",
        "codeItem": 88248,
        "descriptionItem": "ITEM 3",
        "unityItem": "H",
        "quantity": "0,5690000",
        "valueUnity": "40,19"
      },
      {
        "code": 10,
        "description": "REGISTER 1",
        "unity": "KP",
        "typeItem": "I",
        "codeItem": 88267,
        "descriptionItem": "ITEM 4",
        "unityItem": "N",
        "quantity": "0,7890000",
        "valueUnity": "70,33"
      },
      {
        "code": 20,
        "description": "REGISTER 2",
        "unity": "CH",
        "typeItem": "I",
        "codeItem": 1,
        "descriptionItem": "ITEM 1",
        "unityItem": "H",
        "quantity": "30,0000000",
        "valueUnity": "0,17"
      },
      {
        "code": 20,
         "description": "REGISTER 2",
        "unity": "CH",
        "typeItem": "I",
        "codeItem": 2,
        "descriptionItem": "ITEM 2",
        "unityItem": "H",
        "quantity": "3,0000000",
        "valueUnity": "0,07"
      }
    ]
```

My class Java

```java
    public class MyJson {
    @SerializedName("code")
        @Expose
        private Integer code;

        @SerializedName("description")
        @Expose
        private String description;

        @SerializedName("unity")
        @Expose
        private String unity;

        @SerializedName("typeItem")
        @Expose
        private String typeItem;

        @SerializedName("codeItem")
        @Expose
        private Integer codeItem;

        @SerializedName("descriptionItem")
        @Expose
        private String descriptionItem;

        @SerializedName("unityItem")
        @Expose
        private String unityItem;

        @SerializedName("quantity")
        @Expose
        private String quantity;

        @SerializedName("valueUnity")
        @Expose
        private String valueUnity;

        private Double total;

    }
```

My Program

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            Gson gson = new Gson();

                try {

                    File jsonFile = new File("C:\\my_json.json");
                    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(jsonFile), "UTF-8");
                    BufferedReader jsonBuffer = new BufferedReader(reader);

                    MyJson[] myJsonArray = gson.fromJson(jsonBuffer, MyJson[].class);  

                    BigDecimal valueUnity = BigDecimal.ZERO;
                    BigDecimal sumTotal = BigDecimal.ZERO;
                    //
                    Set<MyJson> list = new HashSet<>();

                    for(MyJson myJson : myJsonArray) {

                        if(checkStringNullOrEmpty(myJson.getQuantity()) && checkStringNullOrEmpty(myJson.getValueUnity())) {

                            if(myJson.getCode().equals(myJson.getCode())) {
                                String value1 = myJson.getQuantity().replaceAll( "," , "." ).trim();
                                String value2 = myJson.getValueUnity.replaceAll( "," , "." ).trim();
                                BigDecimal quantity = new BigDecimal(value1);
                                BigDecimal valueUnit = new BigDecimal(value2);
                                valueUnity = quantity.multiply(valueUnit);
                                somaTotal = sumTotal.add(valueUnity);
                                String resultado = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%.2f", valueUnity);
                                String sumTotal2 = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%.2f", sumTotal);
                                myJson.setTotal(new Double(sumTotal2.replaceAll( "," , "." ).trim()));
                                list.add(myJson);

                            }
                        }

                    }

                    for(MyJson myJson : list) {
                        StringBuilder builer = new StringBuilder();
                        builer.append(myJson.getCode()).append(" ");
                        builer.append(myJson.getDescription().toUpperCase()).append(" ");
                        builer.append(myJson.getUnity().toUpperCase()).append(" ");
                        builer.append(myJson.getTotal());

                        System.out.println(builer.toString());
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        private static boolean checkStringNullOrEmpty(String value) {
            if(!value.isEmpty()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

Exit program
```

The calculation is being done wrong when using the Set

```
10 REGISTER 1, KP SUM 130,33
20 REGISTER 2 CH SUM 439,18
```

Comment: I don't think I understand what is your problem.

Comment: The calculation is being done wrong when using the Set 
It does not add up correctly as stated in the calculation that has been explained.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot keep track of multiple running totals (i.e. one for each code) using one total.  Instead you will need one total for each different code.

I would recommend that you use a `Map<Integer, MyJson>` for this purpose.  This would store a number of `MyJson` objects which you could look up by their code.  When handling each `MyJson` object, you check to see if you already have a `MyJson` object with the same code: if you do then you  add to its total, otherwise you add your `MyJson` object to the map.

Get rid of your `Set<MyJson>` variable (which you have somewhat confusingly named `list`) and replace it with the following

```java
            Map<Integer, MyJson> jsonsByCode = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

(You can use a `HashMap<>` instead of a `LinkedHashMap<>` here: I chose to use a `LinkedHashMap<>` because it keeps its entries in the same order they were inserted into it.)

Then, replace all lines from `somaTotal = sumTotal.add(valueUnity);` to `list.add(myJson);` with

```java
                    if (jsonsByCode.containsKey(myJson.getCode())) {
                        // We've seen this code before, so add the value
                        // to the total.
                        MyJson matchingJson = jsonsByCode.get(myJson.getCode());
                        matchingJson.setTotal(matchingJson.getTotal() + valueUnity.doubleValue());
                    } else {
                        // First time seeing this code, so set its total
                        // and add it to the map.
                        myJson.setTotal(valueUnity.doubleValue());
                        jsonsByCode.put(myJson.getCode(), myJson);
                    }
```

(Note that `BigDecimal` values such as `valueUnity` have a `.doubleValue()` method on them, which is the easiest way to convert them to a `double`.)

Then, in the `for` loop below, where you are printing out the values, replace `list` with `jsonsByCode.values()`.

I made these changes to your program and it generated the following output:

```
10 REGISTER 1 KP 2081.60648
20 REGISTER 2 CH 5.31
```

---

Incidentally, your code also contains the following `if` statement:

```java
        if(myJson.getCode().equals(myJson.getCode())) {
            // ....
        }
```

You are comparing `myJson.getCode()` against itself, so this condition will always be `true` (unless of course `myJson.getCode()` returns `null`, in which case you get a `NullPointerException`).  You can just get rid of this check, it doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: I could put the whole class on, because I didn't quite understand what you wanted to explain.

Comment: The sum is different from what is calculated here
The correct thing would be to show:
Code 10:
Calculation:
0,02 * 7,4 =  0,148
10 * 200,31 = 2003,1
0,569 * 40,19 = 22,86811
Sum = 0,148 + 2003,1 + 22,86811 = 2026,116
Code 20:
Calculation:
30 * 0,17 = 5,1
3 * 0,07 = 0,21
Sum = 5,1 + 0,21 = 5,31

10 REGISTER 1 KP 2026,11
20 REGISTER 2 CH 5.31

Comment: @BrunoAlmeida: your calculation of the value for code 10 is incorrect, you're missing the  contribution from the fourth item in your JSON file.  This term contributes 0.789 * 70,33 = 55,49037 to the sum for code 10, and when you add this to the 2026,116 you claim to be the total, you get 2081,606, as in my answer.  Or is there some reason why this fourth item should be ignored?

Comment: @BrunoAlmeida: I don't understand your comment.  I've explained to you the changes you need to make to your code, there's nothing else I need to provide in that respect.  You also haven't answered the question in my previous comment about the fourth JSON item.